# Susy grid with zero margin

Tags: susy-sass

I have a Susy 2 grid with zero gutters (gutters: 0px/150px). Using pull in layout throws error on compile: (Line 54 of _margins.scss: Invalid null operation: "-1050px plus null".)

How do I define zero gutters in Susy so I can use pull without errors?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you [file an issue on github](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed.**

I had 'gutter-position: split'. 
Changing to 'gutter-position: inside' solved the pull/push problem.